# Help on calculating variance and standard deviation - tossing a ring

Tags: probability

You pay \$5 to toss a ring at a set of bottles. If you get a ringer on the small mouth bottle, you win \$35.  If you get the ringer on the medium bottle, you win \$10.  If you get it on the large, you get \$5 (break even). If you miss, you lose what you paid (\$5). The probability distribution of Joe's winnings, accounting for the \$5 he paid to play, are:

Table, respectively:
$$
\begin{matrix}
X & P\\
-\$5 & 0.75\\
0 & 0.1\\
\$10 & 0.1\\
\$35 & 0.05
\end{matrix}
$$

Following are questions:

1. Find the math expectation of Joe’s winnings for a single game.

   - My answer = -5(.75) + 0(.1) + 10(.1) + 35(.05) = -1
2. Find the math expectation of Joe’s winnings after 5 games.

   - My answer =  -1 * (5)
3. Find the variance of Joe’s winnings for a single game.

   - My answer is:
     $$
     \begin{align}
     E(X) &= -5(.75) + 0(.1) + 10(.1) + 35(.05) = -1\\
     Var(X) &= (.75)(-5+1)^2   +  (.1)(0+1)^2  + (.1)(10+1)^2  + (.05)(35+1)^2\\
     Var(X) &= 89
     \end{align}
     $$
4. Find the standard deviation of Joe’s winnings for a single game.

   - My answer  = 9.43
5. Does it pay for Joe to play this game at the fair?  Explain.

   - It doesn't pay.  He can lose $1 per game.
6. Find the cumulative distribution function of Joe’s winnings for a single game and draw its graph.

   - :( clueless

Please let me know if my answers are correct and any help on question 6 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct
2. Correct
3. Correct
4. Correct
5. Basically correct, it's not that he can lose \$1 per game. He actually cannot, he only loses in \$5 increments. Rather, *in the long run* he loses an average of \$ every time he plays. If he plays one million games, and sums all his wins and losses, he will be very close to one million dollars in the hole. The better way to phrase it, as you did earlier, is that the mathematical expectation is to lose \$1 per game.
6. The cumulative distribution function for a discrete random variable $X$ is: $F(X) = P(X \leq x)$. In this case we have the following table:
   $$
   \begin{matrix}
   x & P(X = x) & P(X \leq x)\\
   -5 & 0.75 & 0.75\\
   0 & 0.1 & 0.85\\
   10 & 0.1 & 0.95\\
   35 & 0.05 & 1
   \end{matrix}
   $$

I believe you are being asked to graph the above table with $x$ on the x-axis and the third column on the y-axis as a step function.